# python matplotlib.pyplot syntax error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a function in python, but every time that I go to test it, it just says:

"plt.plot(t,V)
 ^
 SyntaxError, invalid syntax"

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def someFunction(filename, posx, posy, posz):
    //generic code
    //to test 
    //limits...
    data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=",")
    i = 0
    V = 0
    while i < len(data):
        q = data[i,0]
        x = data[i,1]
        y = data[i,2]
        z = data[i,3]
        r = <some computation>
        V += <some computation>
        i += 1

    return V

def plotFunction(filename):
    V = []
    t = []
    for i in np.arange(0,20,0.1):
        t.append(i)
        V.append(someFunction(filename,i,i**2+2,i-3)
    plt.plot(t,V)
    plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
V.append(someFunction(filename,i,i**2+2,i-3))
```

the last closing bracket is missing